# Kotlin Flow Replay Functionality

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there a planned or existing way to replicate RX's replay/refcount functionality in Kotlin Flow?

I need something between a broadcast channel's multicast facility (so consumers don't fight over events), and a regular channel's caching/suspension functionality (so consumers receive some backlog of events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit late, but still might be useful.
There's an [open issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1261) to implement this behavior, so sooner or later we'll have it. Also, there's a discussion about [connectable flow](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1086), but I can't see decision of they implementing it or not.

UPD: Looks like KEEP-1261 is outdated and [1716](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/1716) is more relevant now.

Comment: replay is something else than share. replay saves up emissions even though nobody is connected (if i'm not wrong here). share just works for stuff from the point when you're connected. the former doesn't seem to be catered for coroutine flows...

Comment: @nepa this is a matter of naming. You are correct for Rx, but as I see in kotlin flow they are going to use name `share` with default argument 0 which means no buffer and ability to specify buffer size. Which looks good to me, language allows this and the behavior is similar, so why not?

Comment: Is there a way I can add reply to a certain observer only and not to the producer?

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin Flow current support `shareIn` function to replays the last emitted item to a new collector.
Snippet code from [StateFlow and SharedFlow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#sharein):

```
val latestNews : Flow<List<ArticleHeadline>> = flow {
    ...
}.shareIn(
    externalScope,
    replay = 1,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()
)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can add reply to a certain observer only and not to the producer?